# Returning binary content from a JPF action with Weblogic Portal 10.2

Tags: weblogic, portal, binary-data, jpf

One of the actions of my JPF controller builds up a PDF file and I would like to return this file to the user so that he can download it.

Is it possible to do that or am I forced to write the file somewhere and have my action forward a link to this file? Note that I would like to avoid that as much as possible for security reasons and because I have no way to know when the user has downloaded the file so that I can delete it.

I've tried to access the HttpServletResponse but nothing happens:

```
getResponse().setContentLength(file.getSize());
getResponse().setContentType(file.getMimeType());
getResponse().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + file.getTitle() + "\"");
getResponse().getOutputStream().write(file.getContent());
getResponse().flushBuffer();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have something similar, except returning images instead of a PDF; should be a similar solution, though, I'm guessing.

On a JSP, we have an `IMG` tag, where the `src` is set to:

```
<c:url value="/path/getImage.do?imageId=${imageID}" />
```

(I'm not showing everything, because I'm trying to simplify.)  In your case, maybe it would be a link, where the `href` is done in a similar way.

That `getImage.do` maps to our JPF controller, obviously.  Here's the code from the JPF `getImage()` method, which is the part you're trying to work on:

```
@Jpf.Action(forwards = {
    @Jpf.Forward(name = FWD_SUCCESS, navigateTo = Jpf.NavigateTo.currentPage),
    @Jpf.Forward(name = FWD_FAILURE, navigateTo = Jpf.NavigateTo.currentPage) })
public Forward getImage(final FormType pForm) throws Exception {
  final HttpServletRequest lRequest = getRequest();
  final HttpServletResponse lResponse = getResponse();
  final HttpSession lHttpSession = getSession();
  final String imageIdParam = lRequest.getParameter("imageId");

  final long header = lRequest.getDateHeader("If-Modified-Since");
  final long current = System.currentTimeMillis();

  if (header > 0 && current - header < MAX_AGE_IN_SECS * 1000) {
    lResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED);
    return null;
  }

  try {
    if (imageIdParam == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("imageId is null.");
    }

    // Call to EJB, which is retrieving the image from
    // a separate back-end system
    final ImageType image = getImage(lHttpSession, Long
        .parseLong(imageIdParam));

    if (image == null) {
      lResponse.sendError(404, IMAGE_DOES_NOT_EXIST);
      return null;
    }

    lResponse.setContentType(image.getType());
    lResponse.addDateHeader("Last-Modified", current);
    // public: Allows authenticated responses to be cached.
    lResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + MAX_AGE_IN_SECS
        + ", public");
    lResponse.setHeader("Expires", null);
    lResponse.setHeader("Pragma", null);
    lResponse.getOutputStream().write(image.getContent());

  } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
    LogHelper.error(this.getClass(), "Illegal argument.", e);
    lResponse.sendError(404, IMAGE_DOES_NOT_EXIST);
  } catch (final Exception e) {
    LogHelper.error(this.getClass(), "General exception.", e);
    lResponse.sendError(500);
  }
  return null;
}
```

I've actually removed very little from this method, because there's very little in there that I need to hide from prying eyes--the code is pretty generic, concerned with images, not with business logic.  (I changed some of the data type names, but no big deal.)